# Objective-C / iOS - Resolve duplicated symbols inside a static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, logging, cocoalumberjack

My iOS project used a 3rd party (not open source) static library (i.e. `libA.a`), and this `libA.a` used `CocoaLumberjack`, it compiled `CocoaLumberjack` directly into itself, and the version of `CocoaLumberjack` is unclear.

Now I also want to use `CocoaLumberjack` to track logs in my program, and it will result duplicate symbol errors if I install `CocoaLumberjack` via CocoaPods.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to **hide**
   the `CocoaLumberjack` symbols in `libA.a` so that Xcode won't report symbol errors?
2. Any other `file logger` libraries that can be recommended?

Now I am looking through symbols in `libA.a`, contrasting it with the source of `CocoaLumberjack`, and I am closed to find the version of `CocoaLumberjack` `libA.a` used, my next step should be only including header files of `CocoaLumberjack` in my project. It should work, but I don't like this way.

Comment: Just a update. Finally we get the author of libA.a to remove the old version of CocoaLumberjack from their library.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can unpack the object files from the static library and repack it without the CocoaLumberpack object files.</strike>

Something like:

```
$ ar x libA.a
$ rm cococaLumberjackFile*.o      # Whatever they are called
$ ar cr libA.a *.o
```

If the static library is *fat* (contains multiple CPU architectures) then this becomes *much* more difficult and involves `lipo` and much pain.

EDIT: Just go ahead and use CocoaLumberjack in your code and link with `libA.a`.  It will provide the objects for both the 3rd-party library *and* CocoaLumberjack.

Comment: It looks pretty cool. However, it is possible that `libA.a` is also using `CocoaLumberjack`, if I removed them, I doubt if `libA.a` code will work with latest version of `CocoaLumberjack` or not (because of various changes in methods, etc.). But if I can find out which version of `CocoaLumberjack` `libA.a` used, then I can use your method to include source of `CocoaLumberjack` into my project.

Comment: Give it a try and find out.

Comment: Hmm.. Doesn't work. It says `ar: libA.a is a fat file (use libtool(1) or lipo(1) and ar(1) on it) . ar: libA.a: Inappropriate file type or format`